# How to rewrite url?

Tags: catalog, url

Now every catalog url rewrites to `catalog\category\view`. But I would like to rewrite it to my own controller. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: You can just override the view method of the category controller.

Comment: By extending the Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract Router class in your module you can rewrite catalog Url to your own controller's action for e.g you can refer Mage_CMS module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create config.xml `app/code/local/ MyNameSpace/MyModule/etc`. and past below code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
        </modules>

        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <checkout>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <MyNameSpace_MyModule before="Mage_Catalog">MyNameSpace_MyModule</MyNameSpace_MyModule>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </checkout>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

create file under app/code/local/MyNameSpace/MyModule/controllers/CategoryController.php and put the below code

```
<?php    
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'CategoryController.php';
    class MyNameSpace_MyModule_CategoryController extends Mage_Catalog_CategoryController
    {
       public function viewAction()
       {
           Mage::log("controller..");
           parent::viewAction();
       }
    }
```

Create module file under app/etc/modules/MyNameSpace_MyModule.xml and it code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

More details http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller